# ERR! can not read property 'match' of undefined - react-facebook-login npm package installation

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login, npm-install

I wanna add facebook oAuth authentication for my react application, so I chose to install `react-facebook-login` package npm package but I am getting an error!

> ... npm install --save react-facebook-login
>   npm ERR! can not read property 'match' of undefined

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and fixed it by removing the lockfile (i.e. package-lock.json) and node_modules folder. After that I just called npm install and was able to install desire npm package. Hope it helps.

`rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules`
`npm install`

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the package-lock.json file and install the package you want to install :)